# SelectList when the value required for the bindproperty is a class in asp.net and entity framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, razor-pages

I have a create page for projects. The project requires a name and a client. I am using Entity Framework Core (Code First) and have models for both "Project" and "Client" the property for the client in the Project model is;

```
public Client Client { get; set; }
```

When i first made the page the property was, in error;

```
public int Client { get; set; }
```

Now when I created the create page for the project model it worked with the incorrect property. Now after I have corrected the project model the client value is not being selected on the selectlist when I try to add the project to the database (It says that the value is null, and it is).

Here is the code for populating the selectlist;

```
public void PopulateClientsDropDownList()
        {
            var Clients = from c in _context.Clients
                          orderby c.ClientName
                          select c;


            ClientList = Clients.Select(x => new SelectListItem
            {
                Text = x.ClientName,
                Value = x.id.ToString()
            }).ToList();

        }
```

Here is the code for the actual page

```
<form method="post">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Project.ProjectName" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Project.ProjectName" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Project.ProjectName" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Project.Client" class="control-label"></label>
                <select asp-for="Project.Client" asp-items="Model.ClientList" class="form-control">
                    <option value="">-- Select Client --</option>
                </select>
                <span asp-validation-for="Project.Client" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
```

and here are the models

```
public class Project
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string ProjectName { get; set; }


        //Dates
        [Required]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
        public DateTime UpdateDate { get; set; }


        //Relationships
        [Required]
        public Client Client { get; set; }
        public virtual List<Spread> Spreads { get; set; }

    }
```

```
public class Client
    {
        [Key]
        public int id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string ClientName { get; set; }

    }
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Select Tag Helper` `asp-for` specifies the model property name for the [select](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select) element not a model object name and `asp-items` specifies the [option](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option) elements.

Try to change your `Project` model like below :

```
 public class Project
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string ProjectName { get; set; }


    //Dates
    [Required]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
    public DateTime UpdateDate { get; set; }

    //Relationships
    [Required]
    public int Clientid { get; set; }

    public Client Client { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Spread> Spreads { get; set; }
}
```

PageModel

```
public IActionResult OnGet()
    {
        var Clients = from c in _context.Clients
                      orderby c.ClientName
                      select c;

        ClientList = Clients.Select(x => new SelectListItem
        {
            Text = x.ClientName,
            Value = x.id.ToString()
        }).ToList();

        return Page();
    }

    [BindProperty]
    public Project Project { get; set; }

    [BindProperty]
    public List<SelectListItem> ClientList { get; set; }
```

Create Page

```
<form method="post">
        <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Project.ProjectName" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="Project.ProjectName" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Project.ProjectName" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Project.Client" class="control-label"></label>
            <select asp-for="Project.Clientid" asp-items="Model.ClientList" class="form-control">
                <option value="">-- Select Client --</option>
            </select>

            <span asp-validation-for="Project.Clientid" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
        </div>
    </form>
```

About  Select tag helper , you could refer to the following links :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/working-with-forms?view=aspnetcore-3.0#the-select-tag-helper

https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/forms/select-lists